# Find the complex roots of the equation $z^6+(1+i)z^3+i=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

I am aware that my solution is not correct. Appreciate if someone could point out what I am doing wrong.

Let $w=z^3$, then

\begin{align}
0=z^6+(1+i)z^3+i&=w^2+(1+i)w+i\\
&=\Big(w+\frac{1+i}{2}\Big)^2+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{i}{2}+i\\
\Big(w+\frac{1+i}{2}\Big)^2&=-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{i}{2}-i\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{i}{2}.
\end{align}
Set $$w+\frac{1+i}{2}=x+yi.$$
Then $$(x+yi)^2=x^2-y^2+2xyi=-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{i}{2}$$
$$\implies \quad(1) \quad x^2-y^2=-\frac{1}{4},\quad (2)\quad 2xy=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Futhermore $$|(x+yi)|^2=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}^2=x^2+y^2=\Big|-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{i}{2}\Big|=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}\quad(3)$$

This gives $(x^2+y^2)+(x^2-y^2)\iff 2x^2=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}\implies x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{8}}$.

Similarly $(x^2+y^2)-(x^2-y^2)\iff 2y^2=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{4}\implies y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{8}}.$ ???

Answer (score 1):

Let $z^3=w$.

So we need to solve that
$$w^2+(1+i)w+i=0$$ or
$$(w+1)(w+i)=0$$

Answer (score -1):

\begin{align}
0=z^6+(1+i)z^3+i&=w^2+(1+i)w+i\\
&=\Big(w+\frac{1+i}{2}\Big)^2-\frac{i}{2}+i\\
\end{align}
 as we have
$$(1+i)^2=2i$$